# Develop GoogleVr Cardboard Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr-sdk

Hey Guys can somebody suggest me a good source how to build a GoogleVr Cardboard App for Android. Most of the Tutorials that I saw on Youtube are old Tutorials and the old SDK GoogleVr (old) dosn't work any more
Thanks in advice!
ZZAim

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new on stack :)

Comment: I agree that the question is off topic, however to help you with your quest for knowledge: I recently did a research on the subject and found no such issue - i cant remember if just adding Cardboard to the list of supproted XR's or was there an additional step, I had no trouble findind up to date content

Comment: It worked with oculus, it was easeier